# error with jsrouting-bundle symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony

I have installed the jsrouting-bundle, and this is my code:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".pmcontents").hide();
    $(".pmbox").click(function () {
        $(this).css("font-weight", "normal");
        $(this).next().toggle();
        var myValue = $('this').attr('id');
        var DATA = 'sentValue=' + myValue;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Routing.generate('isread'),
            data: DATA,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("database has been updated");

            }
        });
    });

});
```

Controller:

```
public function isreadAction() {
    $request = $this->get('request');
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        var_dump($request->request->get('sentValue'));
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $pm = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Privatemessage')
                ->findBypmid($request->request->get('sentValue'));

        $pm->setIsRead(true);
        $em->flush();
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

Routing:

```
isread:
    path:   /game/isread
    defaults: { _controller: LoginLoginBundle:Default:isread }
    requirements:
     _method:  POST
```

I get the following error in my console:µ

```
Error: The route "isread" does not exist.
```

So along with the errors that I get on the image below this should be my problem, however I don't know what I have done wrong.

[image: Errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *expose* the route, like:

```
isread:
    path:   /game/isread
    defaults: { _controller: LoginLoginBundle:Default:isread }
    requirements:
     _method:  POST 
    options:            # < add these two
        expose: true    # < lines
```

[» manual](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#generating-uris)

Comment: Now I get the following error:
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/SocProNetbeans/web/app_dev.php/game/isread"

Comment: @HardUser Did the error appear upon changing your routing config or is it the response when following the url? Did you try clearing the app cache? If it's the response then this is a different problem which deserves it's own question/answer.

Comment: I get the error when I do the click event (you can see the event in the javascript code). I cleared the cache using cache:clear in netbeans

Comment: So it's the result when following the url. As I wrote, this is a different problem and has nothing to do with `jsrouting`. Try opening the url *by hand* and have a look at the stack trace you'll get when going through `app_dev.php`. It should tell you more about what might be wrong. My guess is that the `if` is not *entered* and no response is returned, this will normally trigger an error with symfony.

Comment: So I have deleted the _method line in my routing, I still get the error, var_dump doesn't do anything so I can't see whats in $request. If I go straight at the link, var_dump gives me null, logical because there isn't a request